# Go Gin Webframework IntentedJSON not working as expected

Tags: go, go-gin

I am trying out the Gin Framework as a Go newbie. I was looking for a way similar to Node.js "json spaces, 2" and came across the IntentedJSON function of the context (Gin Module). However, when I test it in my browser, it still doesn't give me formatted JSON and looks just like the regular c.JSON response.

Anyone knows where I go wrong here?

```
func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) {
        res, err := getOHLC("BTCUSDT", "1h")
        if err != nil {
            c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, err)
        }
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, res)
    })
    r.Run() // listen and serve on 0.0.0.0:8080 (for windows "localhost:8080")

}
```

Comment: Note that in Go arbitrary function calls don't exit the surrounding function body. You should have an explicit `return` statement after the `c.IndentedJSON` call.

Comment: Sorry I am stupid, I only used IntentedJSON in case of an error :D closed